# Switch from TWTRShareEmailViewController to another controller - Twitter fabric ios sdk

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, twitter-fabric

I am using the below code to jump to another controller from TWTRShareEmailViewController, but it's not navigating. I am having a tab bar controller with navigation controller embedded, tried with pushing the view controller still not working.

```
-(IBAction)loginWithTwitter:(id)sender
 {
   [JTProgressHUD show];
   [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    if (session)
    {

        [self fetchUserEmail];
        [JTProgressHUD hide];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}];
}

-(void)fetchUserEmail
{


if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {
    TWTRShareEmailViewController* shareEmailViewController = [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc] initWithCompletion:^(NSString* email, NSError* error) ) {
           TabBar *bar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
        [self presentViewController:bar animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"error :%@",error);
        }


    }];

   [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
else
{

}

}
```

But it's not going to moving to the next controller. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Posting here,Will helpful for others.

```
-(void)fetchUserEmail
 {
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session])
{
    TWTRShareEmailViewController* shareEmailViewController = [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc] initWithCompletion:^(NSString* email, NSError* error)
    {
        NSLog(@"email %@",email);
        TabBar *bar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Inside the loop");
            [self presentViewController:bar animated:YES completion:nil];

        });



    }];

   [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];




}
else
{

}

}
```